# Determine if $\lim_{z\to i} (|z|+i\cdot Arg(iz))$ exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Show $\lim_{z\to i} (|z|+i\cdot Arg(iz))$ does not exist.

I want to consider the value of the limit as

(1) $z$ approaches $i$ along the unit circle in the first quadrant,

Since $|z|= 1$ is fixed, $\lim_{z\to i} (|z|+i\cdot Arg(iz))$

(2) $z$ approaches $i$ along the unit circle in the second quadrant.

Since $|z|= 1$ is fixed, $\lim_{z\to i} (|z|+i\cdot Arg(iz)) = \lim_{z\to i} \big[|z|+i\cdot (Arg(i)+Arg(z))\big]=\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} (1 + i\cdot (\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}))$

by letting $Arg(z) = \theta$.

However, (2) $z$ approaching $i$ along the unit circle  in the second quadrant means that $\theta \to -\frac{3\pi}{2}$,

which is not in the range of $Arg(z)$!

What have i done wrong? Somebody help me on this problem please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Arg}{Arg}$
In the first case,

$z = e^{i \theta}$, where $\theta < \pi/2$.

Consequently, $\color{red}{\Arg(iz)=\Arg(e^{i (\theta+\pi/2)}) = \theta+\pi/2}$ as $\theta+\pi/2 < \pi$.

In the second case,

$z = e^{i \theta}$, where $\theta > \pi/2$. Consequently, $iz = e^{i(\theta+\pi/2)}$, and $\color{red}{\Arg(iz) = \theta+\pi/2-2\pi=\theta-3\pi/2}$ as $\theta+\pi/2 > \pi$.

To sum up, in the first case,
$$\lim_{z \to i} (|z|+i\Arg(iz)) = 1+i\lim_{\theta\to \pi/2}(\theta+\pi/2)=1+i\pi.$$
On the other hand, for the second case,
$$\lim_{z \to i} (|z|+i\Arg(iz)) = 1+i\lim_{\theta\to \pi/2}(\theta-3\pi/2)=1-i\pi.$$
Therefore, the limit does not exist.

Comment: can you show me the formal proof please? thanks!

Comment: @LittleRookie I've added a couple of more statements to show that the limit does not exist. Hope that helps.

Comment: i had a misconception about the angle. I understand now, thanks!